# Layout that respects hidden controls (Codename One)

Tags: layout, codenameone

Components that are hidden on the form still occupy space while default behaviour should rather be to revalidate container and do not include hidden components, at least in BoxLayout and FlowLayout.

Does cn1 supports layout similar to BoxLayout that does not take into account hidden components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can easily remove/add the component dynamically.